# display a long text in a datagridview cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I am trying to display a text of about 100-500 words contained in a string into two columns of a single row of a datatable which is then set to be the `DataSource` value for a `DataGridView` control.

Right now even though it renders it is very sluggish/scrolling takes forever.

I have already set the `DefaultStyleMode` to `WordWrap = true`, and adjusted the row height to display the text.

Are there any alternatives to speed this up or should i investigate adding a `TextBox` to the `DataGridView`'s cell?

Comment: What about showing only a few characters and make it clickable so when the user clicks on it, the entire text can be shown in a pop-up?

Comment: @Oscar Mederos - I really like that idea. Is there any examples or links that you can point me to which illustrate this idea? Thanks

@V4Vendetta. Yep this is for Windows Forms.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. That's just an idea. Is your task to implement it :)

Answer (score 1):

What about showing only a few characters and make it clickable so when the user clicks on it, the entire text can be shown in a pop-up?

First of all, you must have stored the original text somewhere in your application. Let's suppose you have the texts in an array `string[] texts`

All you have to do is:

- Add only a portion of the text to the `DataGridView` control instead of the entire text

You can do this using `Split` method in the `string` class. Example:

```
string text = "Oscar Mederos";
string portion = text.Substring(0, 3); //portion will be "Osc"
```

You can add `...` at the end of the string if you want.

- Program the event [`CellClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx) of the `DataGridView`.

Suscribe in your application to that event, and do something like:

```
void DataGridView1_OnCellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int rowClicked = e.RowIndex;
    int columnClicked = e.ColumnIndex;

    ///If the column clicked was the one that has the long texts, 
    //just find the original text in 'texts' using 'rowClicked' and show the 
    //message using MessageBox or creating a new Form for that purpose and 
    //showing it using ShowDialog()
}
```

Comment: Oscar, I did something similar to this in one of my apps. The only difference is that instead of showing a few characters, I show an image that looks like a notepad with a pencil. I only show the image if there is text in that cell, so cells with no image indicates there is no text in that cell, and cells with the image indicates it has text in that cell. I thought it worked out great for the users.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde That's a good idea too. There are several ways of doing that. It depends on the imagination of the developer. He could just put a 'hand' cursor when the mouse is over, etc.